# Evidences on Hartshorne's conjecture? References?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Hartshorne's famous conjecture on vector bundles say that any rank $2$ vector bundle over a projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$ with $n\geq 7$ splits into the direct sum of two line bundles.

So my questions are the following:

1) what is an evidence for this conjecture?

2)why is the condition on $n\geq 7$, but not other numbers?

3)any recent survey or reference on this conjecture?

Comment: Regarding 2): Page 4 of this file https://edocs.uis.edu/mmaji2/www/Research/Research%20statement.pdf contains a table of some small examples.

Comment: Thanks Steven, although I knew that that up to $\mathbb{P}^5$ non-spliting vector bundles exist, but this article is really helpful to get a quick survey on this topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12688/nonsingular-normal-schemes/12689#12689) of mine briefly discusses Hartshorne conjecture and  some related questions about smooth subvarieties of $\mathbb P^n$ of small codimensions. It links to Hartshorne's original paper, which I think is still the best source to answer your questions 1) and 2).

As for 3), you can also look at Zolbani's [thesis](https://edocs.uis.edu/mmaji2/www/Research/Dissertation.pdf), which has a lot more details then his research statements mentioned by Steven.

(That's all I know, I would be very interested in what's new about Hartshorne's conjecture as well).

**EDIT**: Today while answering another question I was reminded of a line of research which can be viewed as evidence for Hartshorne's conjecture: smooth subvarieties of small codimension behave cohomologically like complete intersections (this was discussed in Section 2 of Hartshorne original [paper](http://www.ams.org/bull/1974-80-06/S0002-9904-1974-13612-8/)). A paper by [Lyubeznik](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2946619), especially Section 11, has many such results, even for positive characteristic cases. It also includes many relevant references.

Comment: I checked that question. Although I don't know precisely how $S_2$ condition plays its rule in Hartshorne conjecture, I knew that the vanishing of certain local cohomology groups with $i>0$ implies the splitting condition.  By the way, thanks for the reference.

Comment: In codimension 2 situation, one only need to check that the local ring $R$ at the origin of the cone has depth 2 (since you already assume X is smooth, so $R$ is already an isolated singularity). Thus it is basically $H_m^1(R)=0$. 

Comment: The link to Zolbani's thesis doesn't seem to work...

Comment: New link: http://faculty.lagcc.cuny.edu/mmajidi/Research/Dissertation.pdf

Answer (score 14):

I think the original statement of Hartshorne was that for smooth $ X \subset \mathbb{P}^N$ with $ 3/2 \dim(X) > N$, then $X$ is a complete intersection (you recover your statement from this conjecture with the famous construction of Serre). Being a complete intersection implies that $ H^0(\mathbb{P}^N, O_{\mathbb{P}^N}(k)) \rightarrow H^0(X,O_X(k))$ is surjective for all $k$. A variety with such a surjective map for a fixed $k$ is called $k$-normal.

With surprisng new "topologico-geometric" methods, Fyodor Zak proved in the beginning of the 80's that if $3/2\dim(X) + 1 > N$ then $X$ is $1$-normal. He proved morever that for $ 3/2\dim(X) + 1 = N$ there exist only $4$ varieties which are not $1$-normal namely : the 2nd Veronese embedding of $\mathbb{P}^2$ projected down into $\mathbb{P}^4$, the Segre embedding of $\mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^2$ projected down into $\mathbb{P}^7$, the Plucker embedding of the grassmannian of $\mathbb{C}^2 \subset \mathbb{C}^6$ projected down into $ \mathbb{P}^{13}$ and the closed orbit of $E_6$ in $\mathbb{P}^{26}$ projected down into $\mathbb{P}^{25}$. You can read his wonderful book "**Tangents and Secants of Algebraic Varieties**" to get complete proofs of these facts.

If you restrict to the case of varieties defined by quadratic equations (which is a bit limitated but still interesting as a step toward a more complete answer), then Hartshorne conjecure has been proved in that setting by Ionescu and Russo (see http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.2763). Note also that Hartshorne conjecture completely fails for other toric projective Fano varieties, see http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.5546).

Comment: Concerning the last reference: there is a complete description of toric vector bundles due to Klyachko 1989. In his long paper, among other things, he gives an iff condition for all rank 2 toric vector bundles to be split. 


Comment: That's interesting, can you give the title of the paper? Nevertheless I think the result of the last reference I gave is a bit more subtle than the result by Klyachko you metionned. Indeed the bundles constructed by these authors are (if I remember correctly) never toric. 

Comment: It is strange then that they neither check if these bundles are toric nor make reference to Klyachko's article. 

Comment: A. Klyachko, Equivariant vector bundles on toral varieties, Math. USSR Izv. 35 (1990), 337–375. 


Answer (score 7):

A remark similar to Hailong Dao's comment under his answer:

Let $E$ be a vector bundle on $\mathbb{P}^n$. A cohomological criterion (Horrocks' criterion) states that $E$ splits if and only if $H^i(\mathbb{P}^n, E(t))=0$ for $0 < i < n$ and all $t$.

There is a little less well known criterion, due to Evans and Griffiths, which says that we only need to check the vanishing of $H^i(\mathbb{P}^n, E(t))$ for $0 < i < \min(n, rank(E))$ and all $t$.

In particular, in the rank two case, the whole conjecture boils down to the simple claim that $H^1(\mathbb{P}^n, E) = 0$. Since $E$ is trivial on each "standard open" $U_i$, we can describe cohomology classes in this $H^1$ group using explicit Cech cocycles in this covering.

In summary, it is surprising how little we know about such a simple situation!

Comment: I guess that you mean that $H^1(\mathbb{P}^n, E(t))=0$ for any $t\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I mean $E$, not $E(t)$, because if we prove vanishing of $H^1$ for all rank two vector bundles, then in particular we have it for $E(t)$.