# Classification of local and semi-local rings in function fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $C$ be a non-singular algebraic curve over an algebraically closed field $k$, and $F$ a function field of this curve. It is well-known that non-trivial discrete valuation rings of $F$ correspond to points of $C$.

Is there any classification of local and semi-local rings in $F$? What examples of semi-local rings in $F$ do you know?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283525/classification-of-local-and-semi-local-rings-in-function-fields

Comment: I found some classification of semi-local rings by local rings. A semi-local ring $\neq F$ may be expressed as the intersection of a finite number of local rings, no two of which have a place in common, in one and only one way. See http://www.jstor.org/stable/1969773?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents (Rosenlicht M. Equivalence Relations on Algebraic Curves, theorem 3).

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a full answer, just a sketch.

Well, presumably you want all the elements of $k$ to be units in your local and semi-local rings (ie $k \subseteq R$)?  Otherwise things can get very complicated.

I think such a classification does indeed though exist, here's how I would proceed:

Take $R$ to be a local or semi-local (Noetherian?) ring in $F$ that has all elements of $k$ as units.  Consider the normalization $S$ of $R$.  This normalization should be semi-local and an intersection of those DVRs.  Then you can re-obtain $R$ from $S$ by doing a pullback in the category of rings.

See the answers:

[Is there a "geometric" intuition underlying the notion of normal varieties?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109395/is-there-a-geometric-intuition-underlying-the-notion-of-normal-varieties/109486#109486)

and

[Obtaining non-normal varieties by pushout](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186406/obtaining-non-normal-varieties-by-pushout/186650#186650)

The relevant thing is that you noticed that $S = \bigcap R_i$ where the $R_i$s are DVRs, then you would pick ideal an ideal $I \subseteq S$ (which can just be thought of as picking an ideal in each $R_i$) and forming the pullback of the diagram

$$
\{ 
S = \bigcap R_i \to \prod S/I \leftarrow A
\}
$$
where $A$ is some subring of the (usually Artinian) ring $S/I$.

Comment: Of course $k \subsetneq R$. For simplicity, let rings be Noetherian. Karl, thank you for the first answer the question.