# Ring of Integers as subring with most irreducibles

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, number-fields

Let $L$ be a number field. Is it possible to define its ring of integers $R$ by saying it's the subring with (in a fuzzy sense) the "most" irreducibles?

Comment: It seems you're looking for the universal property of normalization, which is the geometric version of "taking the integral closure". See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46/what-is-the-universal-property-of-normalization You might also want to replace "irreducibles" by "prime ideals" in your question.

Comment: You could make "most" less fuzzy by asking: Does the ring of integers satisfy the property that if there is a subring $S$ of $L$ in which $x\in S$ is irreducible, then $x\in R$ and is irreducible or a product of irreducibles.  One problem is that, unless the class number is 1, the ring of integers is not a UFD.  So irreducibles behave badly.  This is why, historically, one uses prime ideals rather than irreducibles.  We have unique factorization of prime ideals.